# how to make git difftool to always export absolute paths

Tags: git, difftool

When using 'git difftool' it passes relative path to external diff application when one of the files is the latest version.

~/.gitconfig

```
[difftool "echo"]
    cmd = echo $LOCAL $REMOTE
    path =
[diff]
    tool = echo
```

example command

```
git difftool e3d654bc65404b9229abc0251a6793ffbfccdee3 6c6b5fd34196402e4fa0e8cf42f681d9fbd5359f

Viewing: 'app/views/shared/_graph.html.slim'
Launch 'echo' [Y/n]: y
app/views/shared/_graph.html.slim /var/folders/fs/3pgvhwkj2vq4qt3q6n74s5880000gn/T//XGFoyj__graph.html.slim
```

In this example `app/views/shared/_graph.html.slim` is relative path which would be passed to external diff application and since it is relative the diff application doesn't know how to open it.

How can I make 'git difftool' to ALWAYS export absolute paths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is solution based on hlovdal and VonC answers which I've ended up using.

~/.git_absolute_path.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

FILE_PATH="$1"

case "$FILE_PATH"
in
        /*)
                NEW_PATH="$FILE_PATH"
                ;;
        *)
                NEW_PATH=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`/"$FILE_PATH"
                ;;
esac

echo "$NEW_PATH"
```

~/.gitconfig

```
[difftool "echo"]
    cmd = echo `~/.git_absolute_path.sh $LOCAL` `~/.git_absolute_path.sh $REMOTE`
    path =
[mergetool "echo"]
    cmd = echo `~/.git_absolute_path.sh $LOCAL` `~/.git_absolute_path.sh $REMOTE` `~/.git_absolute_path.sh $BASE` `~/.git_absolute_path.sh $MERGED`
    trustExitCode = true
[diff]
    tool = echo
```

the difference here is that we are reusing the single script for each path.

Answer (score 4):

Put the echo command inside a wrapper script

```
$ tail -5 ~/.gitconfig
[difftool "echo"]
        cmd = /tmp/test/echo.sh $LOCAL $REMOTE
        path =
[diff]
        tool = echo
$ cat /tmp/test/echo.sh
#!/bin/sh

LOCAL="$1"
REMOTE="$2"

case "$LOCAL"
in
        /*)
                L="$LOCAL"
                ;;
        *)
                L=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`/"$LOCAL"
                ;;
esac

case "$REMOTE"
in
        /*)
                R="$REMOTE"
                ;;
        *)
                R=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`/"$REMOTE"
                ;;
esac

echo "$L" "$R"
$
```

Then it will output the absolute path for files:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   dummy
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$ git difftool

Viewing: 'a/b/c/dummy'
Hit return to launch 'echo': 
/tmp/vsDkDe_dummy /tmp/test/a/b/c/dummy
$
```

Comment: Same idea than my answer, but more detailed. +1

Answer (score 2):

You could use `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` to add before your $LOCAL variable in order to get the full path.

Interestingly enough, there is a patch in progress (February 2014) which would add that very command in order to make difftool work from within a submodule:

"[`[PATCH]` `difftool`: support repositories with `.git-files`](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-difftool-support-repositories-with-git-files-td7604093.html)"

The [`git-difftool.perl#find_worktree`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/384364b5f1aa0c3b7610a1b3c9eca2c210e61b41/git-difftool.perl#L40-L60) becomes

```perl
sub find_worktree 
{ 
    # Git->repository->wc_path() does not honor changes to the working 
    # tree location made by $ENV{GIT_WORK_TREE} or the 'core.worktree' 
    # config variable. 
    return Git::command_oneline('rev-parse', '--show-toplevel'); 
}
```

Comment: Same idea as my answer, but additional information. +1

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not documented, it appears that git interprets `$PWD` as the Print Working Directory Linux command even when invoked from the Windows command prompt and this is the working directory of the git repository.

Therefore, you can use `$PWD` alongside `$BASE`, `$LOCAL`, `$REMOTE` and `$MERGED`.